# Application architecture with data on a shared network, without a database on the server

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I'm currently working on a C# project of an application we'd like to develop. We're brainstorming over the question of sharing the data between users. We'd like to be able to specify a folder where all the files of the application are going to be saved and we'd like to be able to save them on a shared folder (server, different PC or Mac, Nas, etc.).

The deployment would be like so :

- Installation on the first PC, we choose a network drive, share, whatever and create all the files for the application in this location.
- On the second PC we install the application and we choose the same location (on the network), the application doesn't create anything, it sees that it's already existing and it uses these files as the application's data
- Same thing on the other clients

The application's files are going to be documents (most likely XML formatted documents) and when opening the application we want to show all the existing documents. The thing is, we don't only want to have the list of documents and be able to edit their content, we also would like to be able to edit the document's property, so in a way we'd like a file (Sqlite, XML, whatever) representing the list of all the documents and their attributes. Same thing for a list of addresses.

I know all that looks exactly like a client / server with database solution, but this solution is out of the question. I was first looking at SQLite for my data files, but I know concurrency can be a real problem and file lock doesn't work well. The thing is, I would have the same problem with simple XML files (refreshing the content when several users are working, accessing locked files).

So I guess my final question is : Is it feasable? Is there an alternative I didn't see which would allow us to do that more easily?

**EDIT :**

OK I'm not responding to every post or comment, because I'm currently testing concurrency with SQLite. What I did, and please correct me if the way I test this is wrong, is launch X BackgroundWorker which are all going to insert record in a sample database (which is recreated everytime I start the application). I tried launching 100 iterations of INSERT in the database via these backgroundWorkers.

Of course concurrency is working with one application running, it's simply waiting for the last BackgroundWorker to do it's job and then writing the next record. I also tried inserting at (almost) the same time, meaning I put a loop in every BackgroundWorker waiting for a modulo 5 timestamp (every 5 seconds, every BackgroundWorker runs). Again, it's waiting for the previous insert query to end before doing the next and everything's working fine. I even tried it with 500 BackgroundWorkers and it worked fine.

I then tried launching my app several times and running them simultaneously. When doing this I did have some issue. With two instances of my app it was still working fine, but when trying this with 4-5 instances, it got really buggy and I got two types of error : 1. database is locked 2. disk I/O failure. But mostyle locked databases.

What I did was pretty intensive, in the scenario of my application, it will never ever come to 5 processes trying to simultaneously insert 500 hunded rows at the same time (maybe I'll get a concurrency of two or three connections). But what really bugged me and what makes me think my testing method is not really a good one, is that I got these errors trying to work on a database on a shared network, on a NAS AND on my own HDD. Everytime it worked for maybe 30-40 queries then throwing me "database is locked" error.

Am I testing it wrong? Maybe I shouldn't be trying so hard to make this work, but I'm still not convinced that SQLite is not a good alternative to what I'm trying to do, since the concurrency is going to be really small.

Comment: Why can't you use a database server?

Comment: Judging from your question, it seems you want to have a database-like data access on raw xml files. Can you explain why a database is out of the question? I can only guess, but do you know you can store xml files in a database?

Comment: We're targeting very small clients (most of the time without a server, only a external hdd or Nas) and we'd like to be able to use the application on a single PC or share data on several PC, but the project doesn't include developing a server version. We'd also like to propose a full trial version and that doesn't really fit a client/server solution. Last thing : we have a partnership with a client/server application and we see the many problems (access rights, firewall, etc.) occuring in these kind of architectures every day. We don't want that.

Comment: Over 10 years ago I implemented a file-based "archive" (on Solaris) for a provisioning system (Telco). This was a bad design decision (reason: it started as a prototype and the customer *insisted* on not using any kind of DB, relational or even just a datastore). After a bit performance was so bad that we ported everything to Oracle. I strongly suggest you do not spend valuable resources in reinventing wheels and just look for something self contained and low-maintenance (Firebird?)

Answer (score 1):

You right, Sqlite uses file locks on database file, so storing all data files in database would bring write-starvation problem for editing your documents.

May be it's better choice to implement simple optimistic/pessimistic locking by yourself on particular-file level? For example, in case of using pessimistic lock you just don't allow anyone to edit particular file, if somebody already in process of editing it. In this case you will hold lock just on one file, but not on the entire database. If possibility of conflict(editing particular file at the same time) is pretty low, it is better to go with optimistic locking.

Simple optimistic locking implementation:

When user get file for reading - it's OK, no problem here. If user get file for editing, you could calculate hash for this file(or get timestamp of last updated time of the file), and then, when user tries to save edited file, compare current(at the moment of saving) hash/timestamp to make sure that file has not been changed by somebody else. If file has not been changed then it's ok to save it. IF file has been changed, then current user is out of luck, you need to inform him about it. This optimistic scenario is nice when possibility of this "out of luck" is pretty low. Otherwise it's better to stick with pessimistic locking, when you do not allow user even to start file editing if somebody else is doing it.

Comment: On a "single file" basis I get what you're saying and I think it's the way to go. I would still have to allow reading access for locked files though. But I don't know if implementing file lock on network shares is easy... But concerning my "list" of documents, could I still use Sqlite but implement a layer of locking in my own app? The user can read the list at any time, if he tries to edit it it checks if it's locked, if it's not it checks if the user's not altering changes made by another user (and warn the user in case), if it's ok it locks the file, write in it and unlock it. Seems OK?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are talking about optimistic locking scenario and I've just updated answer little bit. And, yes, I think you could use Sqlite not only for storing "list of files", but also for storing info about file-locks, last updated time for files etc, to manage concurrent modifications.

Answer (score 1):

With your optimistic/pessimistic locking, you are ultimately trying to build a database.  Also, you WILL have issues with consistency while trying to keep multiple files in sync with each other.  Think about if you update the "metadata" file, and the write fails half-way through because of a network blip.  File corruption will ensue, and you will be left trying to reconstruct things from backups.

I would suggest a couple of likely solutions:

1)  Host the content yourselves, and let them be pure clients (cloud based deployments are ideal for this).  Most network/firewall issues can be circumvented by using HTTP as your transport (web services).
2)  Have one of the workstations be the "server", which keeps it data files on the NFS.  This will give you transactional integrity, incremental backups, etc.  There are *lots* of good embedded database managements systems to help you manage this complexity.  MS SQL Server even has some great options for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one part of me would like nothing more to say no to this SQLite solution. I hear what you're saying, but I still tried to test SQLite as best as I could to see if it could work (you can see I edited my first post)

Comment: But concerning your two solutions I would be more than glad to use the first one but as we know our customer and their privacy, convincing them to put their data on a server outside of their LAN could be difficult. For your second solution you'd say I still do a clienz / server app only save the data files (not the DB) on a Nas for instance?

Comment: That seems a very reasonable solution.  BTW, I found this after a quick google search:  http://beets.radbox.org/blog/sqlite-nightmare.html   Seems to likely that you have the same problem with SQLLite, and it looks like it can be fixed by recompiling with a flag to enable millisecond timeouts...